# dynamic variables in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, geolocation

I am trying to use HTML5 geocoding to pass dynamic lat and long into an iframe. This is as far as I can get. I can't quite get the lat and lon to work into the iframe src.

How do I pass the variables into the iframe properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myLat(position) {
    text(position.coords.latitude);
}

function myLon(position) {
    text(position.coords.longitude);
}

document.write('<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat='+myLat+'&lon='+myLon+'&name=Your Location"> </iframe>');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for [geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)? Something like the following will do what you want:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    document.write('<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%"' +
        'src="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&name=Your Location"> </iframe>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your iframe first and then set its source from JavaScript:

```
<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src=""> </iframe>


<script>
function myLat(position) {
    text(position.coords.latitude);
}

function myLon(position) {
    text(position.coords.longitude);
}

document.getElementById("forecast_embed").src = "http://forecast.io/embed/#lat="+myLat+"&lon= "+myLon+"&name=Your Location";
</script>
```